# How can I prevent auto-spacing of multiple variables declared on same line in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, formatting, spacing

I want be able to declare variables like this:

```
public static Rectangle CreateFromArray(this Rectangle self, int[] info)
{
    self.X = info[0];      self.Y = info[1];
    self.Width = info[2];  self.Height = info[3];
    return self;
}
```

But VS formats it like this:

```
public static Rectangle CreateFromArray(this Rectangle self,int[] info)
{
    self.X = info[0]; self.Y = info[1];
    self.Width = info[2]; self.Height = info[3];
    return self;
}
```

I tried all the spacing options in Code Style -> Formatting and didn't find any that work.

Comment: IMHO, it would be easier to read, and would look tidier, if they were all on new lines. That's just an opinion, so feel free to ignore it, but I wonder how many people would agree...

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for an answer.

Comment: Using a formatting plugin, my compromise workflow is: edit as needed first. Then apply the built-in VS formatting if I made extensive file-wide changes. Then apply plugin formatting. The plug-in is very easy and fast because it applies itself to contiguous lines without highlighting anything. Yes I must apply the plugin commands to each "chunk" of lines but it's so fast it's not a problem. [I used Align](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cpmcgrath.Codealignment)

Comment: Interesting extension bob, thanks. I was hoping to find a way that wasn't incompatible with VS auto-format, since the changes just get wrecked every time I ctrl+K+D. But I should have known better than to try to do something non-standard in VS, since it usually ends up costing me more time than it will save in my entire career.

Answer (score 1):

Since a `Rectangle` is a struct and therefore a value type, this extension method will not work as expected. The methods gets a **copy** of the original rectangle and will only change this local copy. The original rectangle you passed as argument will remain unchanged!

Return a new Rectangle instead.

```
public static Rectangle RectanlgeFromArray(int[] info)
{
    return new Rectangle(info[0], info[1], info[2], info[3]);
}
```

Note: Since C# 7.2 you can use a ref-Extension method

```
public static Rectangle CreateFromArray(this ref Rectangle self, int[] info)
...
```

But since the original rectangle is completely overwritten, it makes no sense to pass it to the method anyway unless you change the return type to `void` and change it in-place:

```
public static void FillFromArray(this ref Rectangle self, int[] info)
{
    self.X = info[0]; self.Y = info[1];
    self.Width = info[2]; self.Height = info[3];
}
```

Usage:

```
rect.FillFromArray(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
```

Comment: I was trying to keep it on topic, but that is actually quite helpful.